# ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'tweetdata' Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu

I have MySQL installed on an Ubuntu machine. When I run `use TWEETDATA` command it shows me following error

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'tweetdata'
```

But the database `TWEETDATA` does exist in the db. Below is the output of `show databases` command.

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| TWEETDATA          |
| cs340              |
| magento            |
| mysql              |
| ofbiz              |
| ofbizolap          |
| ofbiztenant        |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas what might be wrong here? Could the large size of database cause this. This db was working a couple of days ago and it has over 49 million rows in one table. Could this be an issue?
Furthermore, this is the change we made to `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` file in this period

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
lower_case_table_names=1
```

Could this change have caused any trouble?

Comment: Did you do `use TWEETDATA` or did you do `use tweetdata`? It's case-sensitive, and your error indicates you typed it as lowercase.

Comment: You may want to check your system variable: `lower_case_file_system` It should be `OFF` for Linux.  You may also want to consider: `lower_case_table_names=0` as well especially for debugging purposes.

Comment: @ceejayoz I tried both. It shows db name in lower case in the error each time

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid It seems clear from your sample and the error that you're typing in upper case and MySQL is lower casing it for you.  The first step to figuring this out is likely going to be turning that behavior off.  If you're on Linux (as you are) and using `lower_case_table_names=1` (as you are) it seems pretty clear you won't be able to interact with almost anything stored on the file-system that isn't lower-case.

Comment: @ebyrob the environment variable is empty when I `echo` it one console. I tried both lower and upper case name for variable. Second, I changed the `mysql.cnf` file to only contain `[mysql]` which is what it had contained before we edited it couple of days ago

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid I never said "environment variable" I said "system variable".  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html  MySQL has a thousand settings and I can see the first one you have wrong from the mysql.cnf you helpfully provided.  `lower_case_table_names=1` Try with this as `0` or leave it out.

Comment: ok let me try it with 0 and I let you know. Leaving it out did not help

Comment: using `lower_case_table_names=0` did not help either. Still same issue. Let me try the other variable thing you told me

Comment: I used `mysqld --verbose --help` command. I could not see any variable named `lower_case_file_system`. The `lower_case_table_names` is there and it contains 1 even though I changed it in config file and restarted the service afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Check the data directory of MySQL and confirm is the directory TWEETDATA has required permission and ownership or not ?

If this directory don't have any of the above then set it properly with `chmod and chown` command.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution with us.  I'm sorry I wasn't more help.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out lower_case_table_names=1 and restart your mysqld service,
otherwise mysql will automatically translate uppercase TWEETDATA that you keyed in into lowercase tweetdata, so it'll never find TWEETDATA